# Renew a JWT issued by Azure ACS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api, acs, jwt

We have Azure ACS configured to issue JWT that is valid for 15 minutes.  Once the user is logged-in to the web application (MVC), the user will use the token to access resources on another server (WebAPI). The WebAPI server would then validate that token.

So, is there any way to renew the JWT somehow without interrupting user's work on the web app? We don't want to popup a window and ask the user to sign in again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) for .NET, then it includes a token cache. Per [this blog post](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/09/12/active-directory-authentication-library-adal-v1-for-net-general-availability/):

> One last thing I’d highlight at this point is that every time you get a token from the authority ADAL adds it to a local cache. Every subsequent call to AcquireToken will examine the cache, and if a suitable token is present it will be returned right away. If  a suitable token cannot be found, but there is enough information for obtaining a new one without repeating the entire authentication process (as it is the case with OAuth2 refresh tokens) ADAL will do so automatically. The cache is fully queryable and can be disabled or substituted with your own implementation, but if you don’t need either you don’t even need to know it’s there: AccessToken will use it transparently.

ADAL.NET is available on Nuget here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/

If you aren't using ADAL.NET, provide more info, such as:

- What library you are using
- What is ACS on top of, AD FS or Azure Active Directory

Comment: thanks! I'm handling the callback manually from ACS.  Once the token is received at the callback url, I use Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.JWT to validate the token and write it to a cookie.  The cookie is read by AngularJS and deleted immediately.  Therefore, all WebAPI calls are made by AngularJS directly w/o going to the web server.  I am thinking to use a hidden iframe to renew the token, not sure if that would work.

Comment: It looks like ADAL.NET is designed for desktop/native apps and not for web app, is that correct?

Comment: @qmo - ADAL supports non Windows-RT apps, so web and desktop. If you are doing a Windows Store App, which is restricted to the Windows RT API, then you would have to use Azure Authentication Library (AAL) which is still in preview.

Comment: We are building web apps based on .NET MVC & WebAPI.  I could not find any sample on using ADAL with Web and I've tried using ADAL on web but got an error with AcquireToken.

Comment: Ok, there are a couple sample code items here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj554350.aspx  if you have a more detailed error message it may be better to ask a new question.

Comment: For other folks stumbling across this question from google, here's an example of using ADAL from a web app to call a web api: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/29/using-adals-acquiretokenby-authorizationcode-to-call-a-web-api-from-a-web-app/

Answer (score 0):

We use ACS + ADAL and there seems to be no clever way to refresh the token. Even if the ExpiresOn Time on the Token inside the Cache is due the AcquireToken always returns the stale cached token. We cache the token ourself, so this code is only invoked when the ExpiresOn is due.

I ended up with this dirty hack:

```
                var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(ServiceInfo.AcsUrl);
                if (authContext.TokenCacheStore.Count > 0)
                {
                    authContext.TokenCacheStore.Remove(authContext.TokenCacheStore.First());
                }
                result = authContext.AcquireToken(acsRealm, allProviders.First());
```